# ExCanvas not working in IE7 and IE8 IFrame

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, excanvas, polyfills

I am using IFrame as a popup for IE7 and IE8 but am not able to make ExCanvas work on it. While I checked it out on the developers tools, I was able to see the changes in my canvas tags but was not able to see the rendered effect. Whereas I have tried ExCanvas on a simple web page and it works there. But in the case of an iFrame is just dosent? Can you please explain me why is this happening and is there any other solution to this? As in any other polyfill that can be used?

Comment: As for other Polyfills ther is http://flashcanvas.net/